# Getting an error in oracle 10g.. error:- ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am very new to SQL just doing some practice for my board examinations.
I wrote a command in oracle 10g  but got the following error:-

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

This is my SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE first_table
(name char(50) NOT NULL,
class_roll int(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
board_roll int(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
your_age int(2) DEFAULT=17 CHECK(age>17),
father_age int(2),
CHECK(your_age<father_age));
```

Comment: `DEFAULT=17` should be `DEFAULT 17`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2095331

Comment: There is also an extra comma after father_age int(2)

Comment: same error after removing the comma and = sign...

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an int column, you don't define the length. You could use number(2), but not int(2).
Also, your column check constraint can't reference another column. Fix suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE first_table
(name char(50) NOT NULL,
class_roll number(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
board_roll number(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
your_age number(2) DEFAULT 17 CHECK(your_age >17),
father_age int);
```

Comment: check constraints certainly *can* reference any number of columns from the same table.

Comment: Sorry, that was the error I got when tried to create the table, after fixing the other problems.